# How does Android determine its internet connectivity state?

Tags: android, networking

I am trying to figure out how exactly Android determines its internet connectivity state, particularly in the newer versions. Looking at the source code for the ConnectivityManager, it's not readily apparent how it's doing it.

Does Google document how it performs the connectivity checks when connecting to WiFi, and what endpoints/IPs it uses?

EDIT: These seem to be leads, where Android/Chrome's networking enters a slightly different state, and it then makes queries to a version-specific Google endpoint.

http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/CaptivePortalTracker.java

http://androidxref.com/6.0.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/packages/CaptivePortalLogin/src/com/android/captiveportallogin/CaptivePortalLoginActivity.java

http s://www.chromium.org /chromium-os/chromiumos-design-docs/network-portal-detection

(The third link is broken because I don't have enough reputation to post 3 links or references at once)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do some java coding by yourself, and then you may check with permissions in manifest file..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

These are the some of permissions, which can help you in finding your requirement.

But do some research on java side..

Comment: I'm not really looking to determine this from within an application; I'm more concerned with how Android knows to launch the "Sign in" overlay when a user connects to an access point using UAM.